# iPhone keyboard disappearing after the view disappears

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

For reasons unknown to me, the iPhone keyboard disappears *after* the view segue is complete. So in order to remedy this, I tried to call `resignFirstResponder()` in the function `viewWillDisappear()`. I put my `resignFirstResponder()` function and connected it with a button that initiates a segue. But still the keyboard disappears *after* the view segue is complete.

I also would like to mention the view that is seguing before the keyboard disappears is an unwind segue. So that might be the source of the problem. But I am not a 100 percent sure.

```
@IBOutlet weak var emailAddressTextField: TextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: TextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    emailAddressTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
}

@IBAction func cancelButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    resignFirstResponder()
}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    resignFirstResponder()
}
```

So anybody have a solution to this problem?

Comment: Sorry but I could not understand what you are looking for. You have a ViewController 1 and segueing to VC2 on tap on a button. You had an active keyboard on VC1 which gets dismissed once you go to VC2? If it is so then its working perfectly fine. Please correct me if my understanding is incorrect.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. However, once VC2 is dismissed, and VC1 is shown, THEN, the keyboard disappears. However, if the program were to work correctly, the VC2 should be dismissed and then the keyboard, or the keyboard and then the VC2, AND THEN, the VC1 should show up. Hope that makes more sense.

Comment: The problem is keyboard disappears AFTER the VC1 shows.

Comment: Got you! couple of questions - are you showing alert view on VC1 before moving to VC2? Are you moving to VC2 post call to `cancelButtonTapped `?

Comment: I don't think I'm showing any alert views. And the VC2 is an unwind segue so it exits out of VC2 to VC1. So I'm assuming the unwind segue is called after cancelButtonTapped?

Comment: But I'm not sure if that's true because the keyboard doesn't go away in time.

Comment: I wish I can send you a video to show you. It's so weird, I've never seen this happen before.

Comment: I understood what you are experiencing. I had similar issue when I was throwing alert on my screen. With that my keyboard was being dismissed in a weird fashion in another VC. The clean fix in my case was to use `UIAlertController` but because I was supporting iOS 6 as lowest iOS version, I patch fixed it with inducing a delay in pushing new VC. Let me think if I can suggest you something.

Comment: Neil's answer worked! Haha thank goodness!

Comment: Awesome, glad to know!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to call `-endEditing:` method which causes the view (or one of its embedded text fields) to resign the first responder status.

**Objective-C**

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

**SWIFT**

```
self.view.endEditing(true);
```

Comment: Where would be the best place to call it?

Comment: It only works if it is called inside the method `viewWillDisappear()`. So call it in the function, and IT WORKS!